# React - dynamically and class name

Tags: reactjs

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eutccs?file=index.js)

I'm adding text elements from and array and I like to loop through the elements and updated the claas name.

I'm selecting the elements with their current class name and I want to add the new class name as well.

Is it possible to add the new class name something like

```
element.className={'selected'}
```

=

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {

  const colors = [
    'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Yellow', 'Black'
  ]

  const loopFun = () => {
    for(let i=0; i<colors.length; i++){
      const element = document.getElementsByClassName('test-'+i)
      //element.className={'selected'} 
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='titles'>
      {colors.map((color, i) => (
        <p key={i} className={'title-'+i}>{color}</p>
      ))}

      {loopFun()}

    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('test-'+i)
```

Shouldn't this be:

```js
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('title-'+i)[0]
```

then just add:

```
element.classList.add('selected')
```

However it's considered bad practice to manipulate dom elements directly in react. You should use manipulation on the virtual-dom with the `useRef` hook.

- [useRef docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

### Edit:

```js
const App = () => {

  const colors = [
    'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Yellow', 'Black'
  ]

  const loopFun = () => {
    for(let i=0; i<colors.length; i++){
      const element = document.getElementsByClassName('title-'+i)[0]
      console.log(element)
      element.classList.add('selected')
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    loopFun();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='titles'>
      {colors.map((color, i) => (
        <p key={i} className={'title-'+i}>{color}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

- [docs on how react components render](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_lifecycle.asp)

Comment: I get 'Cannot read property 'add' of undefined' - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ba6ips?file=index.js

Comment: ahhh of course it should be `const element = document.getElementsByClassName('title-'+i)[0]`

Comment: I had tried this but I'm getting 'Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined' - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rwj7fa?file=index.js

Comment: Oh jeez my bad again. You can't actually call the `loopFun()` functions from within the component! you can only do so after it has mounted! to do this you should put the functions in a `useEffect()`. Check out edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you need an extra function to loop over all the elements, if you're already doing that in `map`. Plus calling `loopFun` in render like that is a bad practice and will mostly likely cause infinite loop errors at some point, e.g. if you're dynamically modifying the number of colors.

Instead you can add the class you need when mapping over `colors`:

```
return (
    <div className="titles">
      {colors.map((color, i) => {
        const itemClass = `title${i} selected`;
        return (
          <p key={i} className={itemClass}>
            {color}
          </p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

I'd also suggest looking into [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) library, which makes manipulating class names in React easier.

Comment: I'm trying to create a type of fading type carosel so the colors(in the example) will fade in and out.